# R: t.test output for LaTex

Tags: r, statistics, knitr, sweave, reproducible-research

I wonder if there is any function to redirect the output of `t.test` to `LaTeX`. Some thing like this

```
library(xtable)
xtable(t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep))
```

Comment: `Hmisc::latex` is one option

Comment: Thanks @baptiste for your comment. I used `Hmisc::latex` but it throws the following error: `Error in UseMethod("latex") : 
  no applicable method for 'latex' applied to an object of class "htest"`

Comment: strange, it worked for me

Comment: Doesn't work in `Hmisc_3.12-2`.

Comment: I have `Hmisc_3.14-0`, installed 14 minutes ago

Comment: Thanks @baptiste. I got it. Would you mind to change your comment to answer and guide me how to control digits after decimal places. Thanks

Comment: Amend your question and adapt the title to reflect this, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick.

```
library(schoRsch)
library(xtable)

T.Test <- t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep)
xtable(
  t_out(toutput=T.Test, n.equal = TRUE, welch.df.exact = TRUE, welch.n = NA,
    d.corr = TRUE, print = TRUE)
    )



                      Test                            Results
1 Welch Two Sample t-test: t(17.78) = -1.86, p = .079, d = NA
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-3 package
% Mon Aug 25 21:01:13 2014
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rll}
  \hline
 & Test & Results \\ 
  \hline
1 & Welch Two Sample t-test: & t(17.78) = -1.86, p = .079, d = NA \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple S3-method with `knitr::kable` function:

```
as.data.frame.htest <- function(x) {
    x <- unclass(x)
    names <- c("statistic", "estimate", "parameter", "p.value")
    x <- x[names]
    x <- x[!sapply(x, is.null)]
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        if (!is.null(names(x[[i]])))
            names(x)[i] <- names(x[[i]])
    }
    as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

knitr::kable(t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep), format = "latex")
```

Note: see `str(t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep))` for more details about the `htest` class structure.